# Alternative to localStorage for PHP?

Tags: php, local-storage

Exist an alternative to localStorage in PHP for save big data in locally?

I created a web app that show messages on screen. This messages are stored in a mysql database, but I would run the application too offline by saving messages locally, you can do it?

Comment: Sorry, what? PHP and localStorage have absolutely zero to do with one another. Why do you need an alternative to it?

Comment: You should take a look at HTML5 Web storage.

Comment: Running the app offline - while using PHP? That would mean having a local installation of PHP running on the client machine - and then PHP could write its data anywhere, f.e. a text file. But I have the feeling that was not what you actually meant ...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Unfortunately PHP is unable to store any data locally however there are ways to solve your problem without it but using JS.

Because your data is stored in a DB I assume you still want to keep your data structured offline, for that you could use localstorage and data to be stored as json for easy read or you could use **IndexedDB** (https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/IndexedDB).

They both work great for your problem.

Answer (score 0):

No, under normal circumstances, PHP doesn't run on the user's machine, and therefore can't directly store anything locally. The PHP scripts usually only run on the server, generating the HTML or other content. It's that content which the user actually downloads and views.

If you want to run a web app offline, it will need to use client-side scripting, such as JavaScript.